# Unit Testing class with IStringLocalizer<T>

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I have a class with a constructor, that gets an `IStringLocalizer<T>` injected.

```
public MailBuilder(IStringLocalizer<MailTexte> stringLocalizer)
{ ... }
```

I'm trying to setup the fake of the string localizer:

```
A.CallTo(() => this.stringLocalizer["ConfirmationMailTitel"]).Returns(subject);
```

But I get the message

> IReturnValueArgumentValidationConfiguration LocalizedString does not contain a definition for 'Returns'

The interfact of the IStringLocalizer looks like this:

```
LocalizedString this[string name] { get; }
```

How can I setup this indexer correctly in FakeItEasy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the exception because most likely you are not returning the correct type (ie `subject`)

As shown in the interface, the indexer returns a `LocalizedString`.

Which would mean the mock need to be configured accordingly.

```
//...

var stringLocalizer = A.Fake<IStringLocalizer<MailTexte>>();
key = "ConfirmationMailTitel";
var localizedString = new LocalizedString(key, "desired localised value here");

A.CallTo(() => stringLocalizer["ConfirmationMailTitel"]).Returns(localizedString);

//...
```